# How to fix error GET http:... 404(not found)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to get value of dropdownlist and show textbox but my code dont working

This is my code:
Controller:

```
 public function socaucuachuong($id)
{
    $units = CauHoi::groupBy('chuong')->select('chuong', CauHoi::raw('count(id) as Total'))->where('idmonthi','=', $id)->get()->toArray();
    return view('DeThi::dethi',compact('units'));
}
```

View: `dethi.blade.php`

```
 $('select').select();
function get_units() {
    var id = $('#id_select').val();
    var list = $('#dschuong');
    list.empty();
    var url = "{{ route('dthi.socaucuachuong') }}"+'/'+id;
    var success = function (result) {
        if (result.length <= 0) {
            var item = '<div class="input-field"><input type="text" disabled value="Môn này hiện chưa có câu hỏi nào"></div>';
            list.append(item);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var item = '<div class="input-field"><label for="unit-' + result[i].chuong+ '">Nhập số câu hỏi chương ' + result[i].chuong+ ' (có ' + result[i].Total + ' câu) <span class="failed">(*)</span></label><input type="number" max="' + result[i].Total + '" class="unit_input" onchange="set_sum(' + result[i].Total + ')"  name="unit-' + result[i].chuong+ '" id="unit-' + result[i].chuong+ '" required></div>';
                list.append(item);
            }
        }
    };
    $.get(url, success);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('dethi/socau', 'App\Modules\DeThi\Controllers\DeThiController@socaucuachuong')->name('dethi.socaucuachuong');

Route::resource('dethi', DeThiController::class);
```

And my error when I select dropdownlist:

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

Route

```
Route::get('dethi/socau/{id}', 'App\Modules\DeThi\Controllers\DeThiController@socaucuachuong')->name('dethi.socaucuachuong');
```

Javascript (blade)

```
var url = '{{ "dthi.socaucuachuong", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', id);
```

Comment: i have updated my route but this error: `Missing required parameter for [Route: dethi.socaucuachuong] [URI: dethi/socau/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\khoaluan\app\Modules\DeThi\Views\dethi.blade.php)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a route parameter for the ID you're passing along.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters

Basically, your route needs to be updated to

```
Route::get('dethi/socau/{id}', 'App\Modules\DeThi\Controllers\DeThiController@socaucuachuong')->name('dethi.socaucuachuong');
```

Comment: i have updated my route but this error: `Missing required parameter for [Route: dethi.socaucuachuong] [URI: dethi/socau/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\khoaluan\app\Modules\DeThi\Views\dethi.blade.php)`